# How to remove a defmethod for a struct

Tags: common-lisp

I have 2 destructs: `monster` & `orc`. The `orc` includes `monster`. The generic monster has generic defmethods on it named `monster-show` & `monster-hit`. The `orc` has a specialized `monster-hit` but still keeps the generic `monster-show`. My problem is that I accidentally named the specialized method for the `orc` the wrong name (`monster-show`), so now when I try to use the generic `monster-show`, it runs code that it shouldn't (the wrongly named defmethod I compiled) instead of running the generic method.

Is there a way to get rid of a specialized defmethod in Slime + SBCL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s how I would do it using the slime inspector:

Enter the generic function you want to modify:

```
CL-USER> #'monster-show
#<GENERIC FUNCTION: MONSTER-SHOW>
```

Move your cursor on to it and inspect the object by typing `C-c C-v TAB`

The inspector should show a list of methods for the function identified by their specialisers. Navigate to one and press the button to remove/unbind the method. You can click for this too.

Also by the description of your hierarchy it would probably be wiser to use real classes and not structs. Structs tens not to give a particularly big speedup compared to classes.

Comment: I am adding the M-x route to this in the comments and then I will accept your answer.

`M-x slime-inspect RET #'monster-show`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have an IDE or such, you can use [`remove-method`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_met.htm):

```
(remove-method #'monster-show
               (find-method #'monster-show
                            ()
                            (list (find-class 'orc))))
```

Answer (score 1):

On spacemacs w/ evil mode `:slime-inspect RET #'monster-show`. Select remove-method on the `orc`.